# XSL convert number (20170125102857) to DD-MM-YYY

Tags: date, xslt, numbers, xslt-1.0

Currently I have the following number 20170125102857 which stands for YYYYMMDDHHMMSS (year, month, day, hour, minute, second). how do I convert this number with XSLT 1.0 to just `DD-MM-YYYY` (day-month-year)?

For example:

> 20170125102857 should become 25-01-2017

And yes, it has to be in XSL.

Comment: There are no in-built functions in XSLT-1.0 to do this. Do you have any extension in your XSLT processor?

Comment: I have no extensions (that I am aware of). And I was already afraid there was no build-in function.

Comment: It looks like you will need to use a lot of calls to `substring()` function to achieve this, provided that the length of your Input time-stamp is always fixed.

Comment: Something like: `<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(Timestamp,7,2),'-',substring(Timestamp,5,2),'-',substring(Timestamp,1,4))"/>`

Comment: To my current knowledge it should be always fixed. And there is no easy way to solve this?

Comment: XSLT-1.0 has very limited support for string processing. One has to heavily rely on extension functions to do even simple string processing. Since you do not have an extension, I believe this is as close to easy we have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the input format won't change, you can simply use the `substring()` function for that, as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:variable name="var.myDateToConvert_" select="'20170125102857'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="var.year_" select="substring($var.myDateToConvert_,1,4)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="var.month_" select="substring($var.myDateToConvert_,5,2)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="var.day_" select="substring($var.myDateToConvert_,7,2)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($var.day_,'-',$var.month_,'-',$var.year_)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of the formula above would generate date format `DD-MM-YYYY`.
That is a simple and effortless way to do what you want in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: XSLT strings are 1-indexed. The third parameter of the `substring()` function is the length of the sub-string. So the expression for the year should be like: `<xsl:variable name="var.year_" select="substring($var.myDateToConvert_,1,4)"/>`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I've overlooked that. I'll edit my post. Thanks !

Comment: Could you please change the 0 to a 1? like @ Madeyedexter said. To select 2017 (first 4 numbers) you have to start at 1 (1,4).